# Place circle at middle-right corner of div

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place a circle, with position to be fixed at the middle of the right corner of a div.

The problem is: When i resize the browser, the circle changes position. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="black-box">
                    <span class="circle"></span>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#black-box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 28.3%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 3;

    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
}

/* "BLACK BOX" CIRCLE */
.circle:before {
    position: fixed;
    top: 41%;
    left: 26.6%;
    content: '\25CF';
    font-size: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    color: orange;
}
```

I wish the circle, keeps it position at the right place, even if the browser is resized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "at the middle of the right corner"... do you mean at the middle of the right SIDE?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are going for, but you should start out with a simplified example like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/y116Leqe/  so we can help you with deeper understanding - and not just a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using percentages as your widths, it will change when your width of the screen changes. I would instead recommend using widths in pixels. You can always add media queries to change the width at certain breaking points. This will ensure that the circle never moves. See code below:

```css
#black-box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 420px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 3;

    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
}

/* "BLACK BOX" CIRCLE */
.circle:before {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 390px;
    content: '\25CF';
    font-size: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="black-box">
                    <span class="circle"></span>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box model:

**css**

```
#black-box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 28.3%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 3;

    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
}

/* "BLACK BOX" CIRCLE */
.circle {
    display: flex;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background: orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/y6nexkkk/